# I can't connect to my Apple ID

Tags: macos, mac

I can't connect to my Apple ID due to connection fail as it says, but my connection is good, I can connect to iCloud, visit sites,..., I just can't download books and apps on my Mac any more. I could do it before.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your Mac?

Comment: have you authorised your mac with this account? does this account work on other devices.

Comment: yes i have used this account before on my mac, this problem has occurred recently

Answer (score 1):

Go to your account at https://icloud.com and sign out of all devices. Try signing in your Apple ID after logging out of iCloud on all devices.

Comment: I signed out but i can't sign in again

Comment: You have **two** Apple ID's, *iTunes* & *iCloud* my iTunes forces me to use my *gmail.com* login and will not accept my *icloud.com* Try both.

Comment: @CJDana Unless you set up two entirely separate accounts, you only have one Apple ID. You can have multiple email addresses (including the free iCloud.com address) associated with an Apple ID, but you can only ever login with the email address it was set up with when it was created, which is never going to be an iCloud.com address (since that is created for you after you sign up).

Comment: I can log in using my example@gmail.com that i registered back in 2008 for iTunes or my example@icloud.com account. I always had trouble with iTunes & App Store until I set identical passwords. If you want to see my double login situation, ill post pictures...